# Inputstream to vector<char> - vector iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, boost, vector, stream

first of all, I'm new to C++, coming from Java.
I want to do a simple thing: load a picture from the web using the URDL-libs and save it to a char-vector.
Loading the image works fine, I'm able to save it to the disk, but when I try to load it into a char-vector instead, I get this error **at runtime**:

```
Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable
```

this is my code:

```
urdl::istream inputStream( url );
if( inputStream )
{
    inputStream >> std::noskipws;
    istream_iterator<char> inputStreamIterator( inputStream ), inputStreamEnd;
    string dateiname = "test.png";
    vector<char> imageVector;

    ofstream outputStream( dateiname, ios_base::binary );
    ostream_iterator<char> outputStreamIterator(outputStream);
    copy( inputStreamIterator, inputStreamEnd,  imageVector.begin());
}
```

Comment: So it's failing at the `copy` function?  Which C++ implementation are you using?

Comment: Your code compiles for me. Have you `#include`d all the necessary headers? Which line gives you the error?

Comment: A sorry, it is a runtime error!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `std::vector<char>` has no capacity and you can't use `std::copy` directly. Instead, you should use `std::back_insert_iterator` that will call `push_back()` on your `std::vector`. The easiest way to build such an iterator is to use the `std::back_inserter` template function.

```
std::copy(inputStreamIterator, inputStreamEnd,
    std::back_inserter(imageVector));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the `std::copy` call altogether, by initializing the vector with your input iterators:

```
std::vector<char> imageVector(
    std::istream_iterator<char>(inputStream), 
    std::istream_iterator<char>());
```

or

```
std::vector<char> imageVector(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputStream),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `imageVector.begin()` you should use a `back_insert_iterator`